# Uneven Brightness Curve When Using Digital Triac Dimmer on Neon Transformer

Tags: transformer, triac, load, inductive, dimming

I am working on an AC dimmer project using the following circuit:

[image]

This circuit functions by detecting zero crossings in the AC power input via the LTV814 optocoupler connected to a pull-up input pin on my micrcontroller. The micro then turns on the power switch triac after a timed delay from the zero crossing to achieve pwm style dimming and provide variable amounts of power to the load (done by writing the pin connected to the MOC3052 high until the next zero crossing).

I have noticed when using this circuit on a piece of neon (dimming the ac power input of the neon transformer) that I get an uneven curve to the dimming. There is a smooth fade for most of the range, but then I get a small spike in brightness around the point where it completely fades out. Please see the example below (had to be very compressed to fit in 2mb limit, please forgive the poor quality):

[image]

Any idea what is going on here? I realize this is probably due to the fact that the neon transformer is an inductive device which can present challenges for dimmer circuitry, but I found this circuit specifically when doing research on dimmers one could use with inductive loads. Overall my project works quite well, and this isn't the biggest deal, but I'd like to be able to understand what's going on here and potentially have some control over it if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Discharge lamps have a narrow range of response vs a filament lamp. There is a minimum amount of energy required to keep the arc ‘lit’. At the top end, it tends to flatten out ie past a certain point the lamp doesn’t seem to get any brighter. You might want to add a 100nF/100R snubber to protect the opto and triac. You could try a resistive load to extend the low end. Then have a linearising table in your code to map the input to the restricted phase range.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but just FYI - the dimming scheme you describe is not "PWM" dimming, it's "Leading-Edge" dimming.

Comment: ‘Phase control’ to us oldies.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a SW bug?

Comment: @brhans Good to know the proper term. I'm coming from an audio synthesis background so that's just how I describe it. What is achieved is in fact an example of pulse-width modulation however. You are cutting out a percentage of the AC waveform and therefore modulating pulse width.

Comment: @OskarSkog you mean a bug with the Triac? Or a software bug? Pretty sure it's not software, I've checked the control waveform coming out of the micro on my scope and it looks to be adjusting smoothly just as I would expect

Comment: @Kartman I was wondering about this. The Triac I am using is defined as 'snubberless' by the manufacturer, but maybe an external filter could improve performance. 

Does a snubber filter have to be tuned to the individual inductive load, or can I come up with a one size fits all solution? And will a snubber filter affect the behavior of non-inductive loads?

This project is a standalone dimmer box, so it's meant to be able to work with a lot of different devices, therefore I can't change the internal electronics to work with an individual device. Probably will include a range control tho.

Comment: @EmmettPalaima - yeah technically it is a kind of pulse-width modulation, but there are modern electronic dimmers which can do 'real' PWM dimming over the entire cycle using MOSFETs instead of a TRIAC, so it's useful to correctly differentiate between them.

Comment: @EmmettPalaima, i offered values for a snubber. Using a ‘snubberless’ triac doesn’t preclude the need for a snubber. Note that adding a snubber won’t improve the dimming performance but it might make the triac and opto live a little longer.

Comment: @Kartman thanks for the values. my further question was asking why those values were picked, and what possible interactions the addition of this filter would have with different types of loads. Seeking further understanding beyond just copying values since my intention is to learn by doing this project.

Comment: @Kartman When I added the snubber filter with the values you listed I still get the brightness bump, but now the neon no longer turns fully off at the bottom of the range, but instead stops at a dim but still noticeable brightness. Seems that the small amount of current passing through the snubber is enough to create some small output on the neon transformer.

Comment: The values i gave are ‘standard’ - you can buy a combined R and C with those values. Note that the capacitor should be X2 rated and the resistor a 1W or greater metal film.  The neon transformer presents a small load. Without the snubber the flashing was due to the triac being unable to latch due to insufficient current. The suggestion of adding an incandescent light bulb was to address that issue. Be aware that using phase control to dim discharge lamps has always been a challenge. Nowadays, just about everything  Is led and phase control is dead.